# Linq cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'

Tags: c#, linq

I have problem  with this code

```
string.Join(",", Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("10.10.10.11").Select(x => x.ToString("X2")));
```

i got error

`cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'`

And how can it export to comma seperated txt box ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just convert an IEnumerable to an array of strings by calling the [ToArray()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) extension method:

```
string.Join(",", Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("10.10.10.11").Select(x => x.ToString("X2")).ToArray());
```

Sidenote:

Since .NET 4.0, there's an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421) of `String.Join` that accepts an `IEnumerable<String>`, making the call to `ToArray` obsolete.

Answer (score 4):

you can  try with this ToArray()

```
string.Join(",", Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("10.10.10.11")
   .Select(x => x.ToString("X2")))
   .ToArray();
```