# The type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable <string>' can not be implicitly converted to 'string []'

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a problem and I think you can help me I have this code:

```
string[] A1 = 
    Directory
        .GetFileSystemEntries(textbox2_f2.Text, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Select(System.IO.Path.GetFileName);

for (int i1 = 0; i1 < A1.Length; i1++)
    listbox_2f.Items.Add(A1[i1]);
```

And here is the error:

> The type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable ' can not be
>   implicitly converted to 'string []'. There is already an explicit
>   conversion exists.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Because you are assigning `IEnumerable<T>` to a `string[]` variable. Simply call `.ToArray()` and everything will work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string\[\]'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773967/linq-cannot-convert-from-system-collections-generic-ienumerablestring-to-st)

Comment: @Fyodor not a duplicate in some ways, since an array is not strictly required, and the enumerable could be used directly.

Comment: @crashmstr I think over the SO there must be a lots of another answers containing suggestions to use `var` instead of `string[]` and so on. This question can be answered though, but it must contain links to almost the same questions.

Comment: @Fyodor everything else I'm finding deals with calling a function that requires a `string[]` or `object[]`, so `ToArray()` is the *only* answer. It is not so much about using `var` in this case as not needing to convert it and `var` makes that simpler.

Comment: @crashmstr Searched a little bit more and found out that you are totally right, there are too few answers which would remind that in many situations `var` can be used.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(textbox2_f2.Text, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Select(System.IO.Path.GetFileName)
    .ToArray()
```

Comment: @L.B except the `Select` on the end does not!

Comment: @crashmstr `GetFileSystemEntries` returns string array, SO this can be answer to the exception in question...

Comment: @Upvoters, There is no method that returns `IEnumerable` in the question. So what does this post answer?

Comment: @L.B yes... `GetFileSystemEntries` returns a `string[]`, you take the `string[]` and do a `Select` on that `string[]` then you get an `IEnumerable`!

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(textbox2_f2.Text, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Returns a `string[]`, which is *great*.

But then you put a `Select` on top of that. `Select` returns an `IEnumerable`, which cannot be assigned to an array directly.

You can then call `ToArray()` and use as you are, but you could also use the `IEnumerable` more directly (and save a little time that the conversion takes).

```
//A1 will be IEnumerable<String>
var A1 = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(textbox2_f2.Text, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Select(System.IO.Path.GetFileName);

foreach (var a in A1)
{
    listbox_2f.Items.Add(a);
}
```